# Jasper Report 6.6.0 can't connect to bean collection data adapter

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I Migrated to Java 9 very soon. I'm using JavaFX Framework. I have faced a problem trying to design reports via Jaspersoft studio community edition.

I have added my project classes file to Java Build path inside Jaspersoft studio. When i start creating a collection of bean data adapter i start getting issues:
Jasper report hung ( not showing any message neither successful nor error message).

[image]

Also, in Dataset and Query dialog, it can't retrive bean properties automatically.

[image]
I think is Java 9 compatiblity issue, but i don't know how make it working. 
and i wish Experts can help me.